# Recommended resources for server tuning and security checklist for production Linux server deployment

Tags: linux, security, performance, filesystems, optimization

There are many questions on server tuning and security checklist are being closed.

So, I am not asking for the exact detail.

Please point me to the resources you find it is helpful (no matter web server, db server etc) and worth reading (and still relevant, e.g. no more RedHat 6).

Comment: If you can write an entire book (or series of books) on a subject, it's not something that can be answered in a single ServerFault question.

Comment: I would suggest perusing [tag:security] and our [security.se] sister site.  The reason these questions are being closed is because it is impossible to provide a good, general answer to them. Security is not a product - it is a state of mind and an approach to designing systems. You need to determine the steps required to build and maintain secure systems based on your environment and requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the [**CIS Security Benchmarks**](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/browse/index.cfm?category=benchmarks.os.linux) for the specific Linux distribution you plan to use.

Here is the [**CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Benchmark v1.1.0**](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/show-single/?file=rhel6.110).